# PreparedStatement won't ever timeout even if explicitly set

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, hikaricp

I am trying to simulate an scenario where my service loses connection to a database and cannot do an `INSERT` by blocking the connection with iptables, but I can't make the `executeQuery()` method to timeout.

What I did is setting a timeout for the PreparedStatement like this `statement.setQueryTimeout(5)`. Here is the code.

```
HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();

config.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://db-url/db");
config.setUsername("user");
config.setPassword("passwd");

config.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
config.setAutoCommit(false);
config.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
config.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
config.addDataSourceProperty("autoReconnect", "true");

final HikariDataSource pool = new HikariDataSource(config);

final String query = "INSERT INTO xtable VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

try ( Connection connection = pool.getConnection() )
{
    try ( PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(query) )
    {
        // this is what I expect to work
        statement.setQueryTimeout(5);

        for ( Info info : infos )
        {
            statement.setString(1, info.getValue1());
            statement.setString(2, info.getValue2());
            statement.setString(3, info.getValue3());
            statement.setString(4, info.getValue4());
            statement.setString(5, info.getValue5());

            try
            {
                System.out.println("Waiting");
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                // I use this sleep to ban the database url with iptables
                // to simulate a disconnection
                System.out.println("Waited");
            }
            catch ( InterruptedException e )
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Before executeQuery");
            statement.executeQuery();
            // I assumed that this would timeout after 5 seconds
            // But it never reaches the next System.out.print
            System.out.println("After executeQuery");
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Before commit");
    connection.commit();
    System.out.println("After commit");
}
catch ( SQLException e )
{
    log.error("Couldn't execute query", e);
}
```

The output would be:

```
Waiting
Waited
Before executeQuery
```

and then it hangs forever... What can I do to make it throw an Exception?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `Connection.setNetworkTimeout()` *in a try-finally*.

```
private final static Executor immediateExecutor = Runnable::run;

try ( Connection connection = pool.getConnection() ) {
   int timeout = connection.getNetworkTimeout();
   connection.setNetworkTimeout(immediateExecutor, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(5));
   ...
   try (PreparedStatement...) {
      ...
   }
   finally {
      connection.setNetworkTimeout(timeout);
   }
}
finally {
   ...
}
```

You are suffering from unacknowledged TCP traffic, which can hang a connection if a network timeout is not set.

Comment: It seems to be working just fine, thanks!
Two things bother me: one, in the connection.close() it thows and uncatched Exception because it cannot be closed since the network timeout happened.
Also: do I have to set this timeout every time? If I have a Hikari pool it seems nonsense to set it for every time I need a connection, right? I mean, mostly because I'd keep on creating Executors.

Comment: Another option is to set network timeout at the driver level — globally.  In that case, I would suggest setting it to 3x your longest query time.

Comment: Just one last note.  You do not need to keep creating Executors.  As the example above, you can (should) create a static Executor, and that executor (in the case of MySQL) should execute the Runnable immediately, rather than queueing or passing off to another thread.

Comment: Good advise, I'll try that. I couldn't set the network timeout at the jdbc driver level. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You always could:

```
try{
     preparedstatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
     preparedstatement.setQueryTimeout(seconds);
}
```

Instead of what you did. Maybe that would work better.
Same thing goes for the:

```
Connection connection = pool.getConnection()
```

Comment: What difference would that make?

Comment: @fcasanova when you debug it is much easier to tell which line threw which exception or error after which value. It's not an answer but a suggestion to find why it is not working